# Являются ли однокоренными слова задохнуться, одышка, придыхание, воздыхатель, вдохновлять?

Tags: этимология

Являются ли однокоренными слова задохнуться, одышка, придыхание, воздыхатель, вдохновлять?

Comment: Смежный вопрос [о дыхании.](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/42080/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слова однокоренные, корень ДЫХ/ДЫШ/ДОХ, чередование Х/Ш и Ы/О в корне.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, сомнений нет: эти все слова являются однокоренными

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно. У них одна семантическая(смысловая) основа - дыхание, хотя корень и трансформируется. Делая первый в**дох**, мы запускаем процесс - **дых**ание, начинаем **дыш**ать.

Comment: Делая первый ВДОХ, начинаем ДЫШАТЬ, тысячу извинений, ВОЗДУХОМ